# How to process output of find command in a for loop correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to loop through the output of a find command like this -

```
SRC=`find /path1/ -name file1.jar | head -1`
DST=`find /path2/ -name *metastore.*`
for VAR in $DST
  do
    cp -v $SRC `dirname $VAR`
  done
```

I get an error in `cp`  -

```
Copying /path1/path11/file.jar to /path2/path21/metastore-1.jar
/path2/path22/metastore-2.jar
`/path1/path11/file.jar' -> `/path2/path21/metastore-1.jar\n/path2/path22/metastore-1.jar'
cp: cannot create regular file `/path2/path21/metastore-1.jar\n/path2/path22/metastore-1.jar': No such file or directory
```

This piece of code executes as part of a build script which fails, but when I try to run the same piece of code independent of the script (on the terminal), it seems to work as expected.

Missing something silly here, will appreciate any help!

Comment: Note the `\n` in your file name (you actually having two files).

Comment: yes, hence the for loop. I am just not expecting the \n

Comment: You should probably check your script at http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human help, there is a number of bugs which are easily diagnosed and fixed.